# Custom inclusion templatetag with djangoCMS render_model

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-cms

I have created a website with djangoCMS and make heavy use of apphooks, cms plugins, wizards, etc. We have a simple app with just one model holding the core data that should be displayed on the homepage.

**`models.py`**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.urls import reverse

from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderField
from djangocms_text_ckeditor.fields import HTMLField


class Programme(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    introduction = HTMLField()
    overview = PlaceholderField(
        'programme_overview',
        related_name='programmes_overview'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'programmes:programme-detail',
            kwargs={'slug': self.slug}
        )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Programme, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I decided to create a custom inclusion templatetag for this purpose.

**`templatetags/programmes_tags`**

```
from django import template

from ..models import Programme

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('programmes/programme_list.html')
def programme_list():
    programmes = Programme.objects.all()
    return {'programmes': programmes}
```

In the template I use `render_model` from the `cms_tags`, because the editors should be able to edit the contents in the frontend. Here is the template:

**`templates/programmes/programme_list.html`**

```
{% load cms_tags %}

{% for programme in programmes %}
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center flex-item">
        <div class="service-box">
            <i class="fa fa-4x {{ programme.icon }} text-primary" style="visibility:visible;"></i>
            <h3>
                <a href="{% url 'programmes:programme-detail' programme.slug %}">
                    {{ programme.name }}
                </a>
            </h3>
            <p class="text-muted">
                {% render_model programme 'introduction' %}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The tag is now used in the template for the homepage:

```
{% load programmes_tags %}
{% programme_list %}
```

When I open the homepage it throws an error:

```
KeyError: 'request'
```

Obviously the `render_model` tag needs to access the `request`. When I try to change the templatetag like this:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('programmes/programme_list.html', takes_context=True)
def programme_list(context):
    programmes = Programme.objects.all()
    context.update({'programmes': programmes})
    return context
```

the `request` is passed as part of the **RequestContext**, but then this error is thrown:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 1; 2 is required
```

How should I properly update the **RequestContext**?
If using a templatetag is not the right approach, please point out what would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let takes_context be there and use your old code. Haven't tested this.

```
@register.inclusion_tag('programmes/programme_list.html', takes_context=True)
def programme_list(context):
    request = context['request']
    programmes = Programme.objects.all()
    return {'programmes': programmes, 'request': request}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried that too, but it doesn't help. The error thrown is: `django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: You must enable the 'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai' template context processor or use 'sekizai.context.SekizaiContext' to render your templates.`

Comment: And I should note that `sekizai.context_processors.sekizai` is present in the settings in `TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['context_processors']`.